# sentence with 2 tenses (present perfect and past simple)

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Is it correct to reply to someone:

Context : I sent an email 1 hour ago and he replied me 10 min ago, and I want to tell a colleage.

1. I sent an email and he replied that {message}.
2. Or (I sent an email and he has just replied/has replied that) because the action "sent" is past
3. Or (I have sent an email and he has just replied/has replied that) because present relevance

To me, all could be good, same signification (the first for AE and the third for BE but what about the second...)

Comment: All of those versions are possible. (NB it's _he replied to me_ or _to it_.)

Comment: All are possible but to say the same thing ?

Comment: Yes - I would have told you if any of them had a different meaning.